# What is the difference whether a space is used between number and unit for temperature?

Tags: temperature, conventions, notation, soft-question, units

When talking about temperature, or temperature change, -32.5 ℃ (with space), and -32.5℃ (no space) are two common expressions. Are they the same?

If there is no space is used, there is a problem about priority. What is the calculation order of negative temperature quantity (e.g., the temperature today is -32.5℃, or the temperature change of the object is -32.5℃)? Is -32.5℃ equivalent to (-32.5) ℃ (negative first, I believe it’s equivalent to the expression with space, -32.5 ℃) or -(32.5℃) (unit first)?

Comment: @Poutnik The comments seem more like an answer and we strongly discourage people from using comments to answer.  Also answers potentially get a lot more reputation points than comments.

Comment: Is rather matter of not fully unified typographic conventions than of operator priority.  For more, see [wikipedia.org  Degree_symbol#Typography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_symbol#Typography)

Comment: Since this is a question of typography, it might be better suited for [English.SE].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about typography rather than about physics.

Comment: More like a physics-related misconception that a unit is some type of operator that outputs a different magnitude result depending on the sign of the operand. Read the paragraph addressing “priority.” This is a more appropriate site than ELU Stack Exchange for the corresponding discussion.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, in the metric system, there is always a space between the number and the unit.
All the rules relative to the metric system are described on the NIST website [there](https://www.nist.gov/pml/owm/writing-si-metric-system-units).

One can read for instance:

"**Spacing**

A space is used between the number and the symbol to which it refers. For example: 7 m, 31.4 kg, 37 °C.

When a metric value is used as a one-thought modifier before a noun, hyphenating the quantity is not necessary. However, if a hyphen is used, write out the name of the metric quantity with the hyphen between the numeral and the quantity. For example:

a 2-liter bottle, NOT a 2-L bottle;
a 100-meter relay, NOT a 100-m relay;
35-millimeter film, NOT 35-mm film
Spaces are not used between prefixes and unit names nor between prefix symbols and unit symbols. Examples: milligram, mg (NOT milli-gram or m-g); kilometer, km (NOT kilo-meter or k-m); terahertz, THz (NOT tera-hertz or T-Hz)."

Comment: And generally the ‘space’ should be fixed width and non-breaking.